# Any way to boot an OS from usb flash drive and run directly on a monitor with USB port?

Tags: boot, usb-flash-drive, operating-systems

Is there any way to boot an OS from usb flash drive and run directly on a  monitor with USB port?

I have an LCD monitor with USB port. Can I just load an OS on a flash drive and run it on monitor?

Answer (score 7):

No, you can't do that. Your monitor would need a CPU, RAM and some other stuff. Your monitor most likely only has a USB hub which will connect to your computer's USB port.

Comment: and if it had CPU/Ram and other stuff, it'd be an all in one, not a monitor. I suppose the only other way it would be possible would be magic.